# Semi continuity of functional

Tags: functional-analysis

I am a little bit confuse with lower semicontinuity of functional. Let $\varphi: E\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ where $E$ is a functional space. Why $\varphi$ is lower semi continuous at $\bar u$ if $\liminf_{n\to \infty }\varphi(u_n)\geq \varphi(\bar u)$ whenever $u_n\to \bar u$ weakly. Shouldn't it be $\liminf_{n\to \infty }\varphi(u_n)\geq \varphi(\bar u)$ whenever $u_n\to u$ strongly ? And if not, why ?

By the way, does someone know a well introduction to lower semicoutinuous function ? I really have problem to understand it properly... it's a bit confuse in my mind.

Comment: Both definitions are indeed legitimate: one is weak-lsc, the other (strong)-lsc.

Answer (score 0):

The main aim of introducing the notion of lower semi-continuity is to relax the continuity assumption in Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem (attaining minimum points), If $f:R^n \rightarrow R \cup \{\infty \}$ is lsu and then $f$ attains its minimum on any compact set. Now what if we want generalize this to infinite dimensions. It is okay, and it still works but in infinite dimension spaces we can also weekend the compactness (which highly restrictive) via weak-compactness, but price to pay is that you must strength (strong)lower semi-continuity via weak lsu.